# Is it possible to embed Blender/Freecad in a python program?

Tags: python, blender, freecad

I am writing a program using python, in which some 3D plot functions are needed like importing OBJ files, view 3d objects in different views and so on

I know Blender and Freecad can work with python. Is it possible to embed them into a pure python script so that I can write my own program without opening Blender and Freecad itself? As I saw something like:

```
import bpy
import Blender
```

Also, is there any documentation for this?